# Azure quotas/limits based on running virtual machines

Tags: azure

Are there any quotas or limits in Azure that depend on the number of running virtual machines? In other words, does changing the status of a VM from 'stopped' to 'running' affect the utilization of this limit?

In AWS, there is a quota called 'Running On-Demand Standard (A, C, D, H, I, M, R, T, Z) instances,' which makes it easy to monitor the number of running instances in a specific region.

Everything I've found so far in the Azure pertains to the total number of created virtual machines, and even the core (vCPU) limits do not distinguish between VMs that are running and those that are stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes see here for more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#virtual-machines-limits

Virtual Machines limits - Azure Resource Manager
The following limits apply when you use Azure Resource Manager and Azure resource groups.

Resource    Limit

- VMs per subscription  25,000 per region.
- VM total cores per subscription   20 per region. Contact support to increase limit.
- VM per series, such as Dv2 and F, cores per subscription  20 per region. Contact support to increase limit.
- Availability sets per subscription    2,500 per region.
- Virtual machines per availability set 200
- Proximity placement groups per resource group 800
- Certificates per availability set 199
- Certificates per subscription Unlimited